# Pass an an object as an argument

Tags: ruby, arguments

I have the following method that is just too long:

```
def combine_atoms
  @left.each do |chemical|
    chemical.chem_species.each do |atom|
      if @left_total[atom[0]].nil?
        @left_total[atom[0]] = atom[1]
      else
        @left_total[atom[0]] += atom[1]
      end
    end
  end

  @right.each do |chemical|
    chemical.chem_species.each do |atom|
      if @right_total[atom[0]].nil?
        @right_total[atom[0]] = atom[1]
      else
        @right_total[atom[0]] += atom[1]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

How could one pass `@left` and `@left_total` as arguments, to reduce the number of lines of code in half using ruby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can separate a loop from `combine_atoms` method to a new one with arguments like this:

```
def combine_atoms
  @left_total = combine_part(@left, @left_total)
  @right_total = combine_part(@right, @right_total)
end

def combine_part(part, total)
  part.each do |chemical|
    chemical.chem_species.each do |atom|
      if total[atom[0]].nil?
        total[atom[0]] = atom[1]
      else
        total[atom[0]] += atom[1]
      end
    end
  end
end
```